# Destructuring and sort

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Hope that someone can help a newbie in React.js and generally javascript.
I want to sort an array and place the sorted array in a new array.
Now my initial array is a little bit complex for me, and I don't know how to destructure it and sort it.

It's my array:
Compose by another array and an empty function for now.

```
{items: Array(4), setItems: ƒ}
```

My main issue is that I want to sort the inside array by name, and output the parent array sorted by name. But what is complicated to understand for me, is the fact that inside array is sort by index...

```
    items: Array(4)
    
    0: {name: "bulbasaur", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/"}
    1: {name: "ivysaur", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/"}
    2: {name: "venusaur", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3/"}
    3: {name: "charmander", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/4/"}
    
    setItems: ƒ ()
```

Thanks to help me figure out my issue and explain me the whole method

Comment: You want to sort the array by the alphabetical order of the ```name``` property of the objects inside ?

Comment: Exactly. Well described

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const data = {
  items: [{
      name: "bulbasaur",
      url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/"
    },
    {
      name: "ivysaur",
      url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/"
    },
    {
      name: "venusaur",
      url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3/"
    },
    {
      name: "Acharmander",
      url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/4/"
    }
  ],
  setItems: () => {}
}

const newData = {
  // Takes data and sorts it by name
  items: data.items.sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : ((b.name > a.name) ? -1 : 0)),
  setItems: data.setItems
}


console.log(newData)
```

Comment: Great to hear. You can read more about array sort here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1):

You can sort your array of objects by alphabetical order of the `name` property using `localeCompare`

`array.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));`

Comment: I knew this methode...My issue is the imbrication of object before sorting

Answer (score 0):

I achieve my issue by this way:

```
console.log(props.items.items.sort( function(a, b){
  let nameA = a.name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  let nameB = b.name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  if (nameA < nameB) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (nameA > nameB) {
    return 1;
  }

  // names must be equal
  return 0;
}))
```